# What is the role of the "class" function in my Processing sketch?

Tags: function, class, processing

I just need a confirmation about the role of the class function in my Processing sketch. My program is a Snake (the game Snake).
I think it is used in order to connect all the points of the snake so that they can follow each other.
Or maybe it's something else. Hope you can help me out on this.
The class function appears at the end of the program.

```
ArrayList snake;      // l'ArrayList qui va contenir les elements du serpent
int snakeTaille = 3;  // la taille initial du serpent

int positionX = 0;   // position sur l'axe des X de la tete du serpent
int positionY = 0;   // et sur l'axe des Y
int direction = 1;   // la direction initiale

Point pomme;         // la position de la pomme

int colonnes = 50;   // la taille de la grille notre jeu en lignes et colonnes
int lignes = 43;
int pas = 10;        // le pas de la grille du jeu

int tempo = 100;     // la tempo du déplacement du serpent 
long dernierPas = 0;  

int score = 0;       // le score
int essais = 0;      // le nombre d'essai

boolean commencer = false;

// la direction est codée par un nombre qui représente le Nord, Sud, Est ou Ouest
//    0 = N
// 3 = O  +  1 = E
//    2 = S

import ddf.minim.*;//C'est cette instruction (que vous pouvez saisir à la main si vous le voulez) qui importera l'ensemble des fonctionnalités de la bibliothèque Minim pour les rendre accessibles à notre programme. C'est à partir de cette instruction import ddf.minim.*; que notre sketch va pouvoir jouer du son.
AudioPlayer player;
Minim minim;

void setup() {
 minim = new Minim(this); // on appelle le player.
  player = minim.loadFile("Mélodie snake.wav",2048); // on sélectionne la mélodie.
  player.loop();//musique infiniment

  size(500,500); // la taille du sketch est celle de la grille * le pas de la grille
  textAlign(CENTER);
  noStroke();//pas de contours

  // à sa naissance le serpent est placé au centre de la grille du jeu
  positionX = colonnes/2; 
  positionY = lignes/2;

  snake = new ArrayList(); // on initialise l'ArrayList du serpent
  snake.add(new Point(positionX, positionY)); // on y ajoute le premier element

  // la pomme est créée à une position aléatoire
  pomme = new Point((int)random(colonnes), (int)random(lignes));

  dernierPas = millis();
}

void draw() { 
 noStroke();
  background(40,150,250); 
  fill(0);// coloration en noir du rectangle
 rect(50,430,400,500);// rectangle noir du bas
 fill(120,10,60);
  rect(0,430,50,75);//petit rectangle rose en bas à gauche
 rect(450,430,50,75);//petit rectangle rose en bas à droite


  stroke(120,10,60);//couleur de l'animation automatique
  for(int i = 200; i < player.bufferSize() - 200; i++)// Endroit où se place l'animation (abcisse x)
  {
    float x1 = map( i, 0, player.bufferSize(), 0, width );
    float x2 = map( i+1, 0, player.bufferSize(), 0, width );
    line( x1, 465 + player.left.get(i)*30, x2, 465 + player.left.get(i+1)*30 );// endroit où se place l'animation (ordonnées)
    line( x1, 465 + player.right.get(i)*30, x2, 465 + player.right.get(i+1)*30 );// endroit où se place l'animation (ordonnées)
  }
  if (commencer==false) {
    fill(153,5,5);
    text("Bienvenue dans SNAKE\nNouvelle partie?\nEssayez d'atteindre 15 points pour gagner !", width/2, height/2);
    return;
  }

  if (millis()>dernierPas+tempo) { // si 'tempo' milliscondes se sont écoulées on bouge le serpent 

    // on determine la position de la tête en fonction de la direction
    if (direction == 0) positionY -= 1; // nord
    if (direction == 1) positionX += 1; // est
    if (direction == 2) positionY += 1; // sud
    if (direction == 3) positionX -= 1; // ouest

    // si le serpent sort du cadre on perd.
    if ((positionX<0)||(positionX>=colonnes)||(positionY<0)||(positionY>=lignes))  {
      snake.clear(); // on vide l'ArrayList du serpent
      positionX = colonnes/2; // et on repositionne la tête du serpent au centre
      positionY = lignes/2;
      snakeTaille = 3;  // on remet le serpent a sa taille initiale
      tempo = 100; // on remet le tempo a 120
      essais ++;
      score=0;
    }

    // si le serpent se mord la queue on perd aussi
    for (int i = snake.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
      Point snakeElement = (Point) snake.get(i);
      if (snakeElement.touche(positionX, positionY)) { // la tête est-elle sur le même point qu'un des elements du serpent ?
        snake.clear(); // on vide le arrayList du serpent
        positionX = colonnes/2; // on repositionne le serpent au centre
        positionY = lignes/2;
        snakeTaille = 3;  // on remet le serpent a sa taille initiale
        tempo = 100; // on remet le tempo a 250
        essais ++;
        score=0;
        break; // on peut sortir prématurement de la boucle 'for'
      }
      // quand on a atteint le nombre d'essai maximum
      if (essais == 5) {
        positionX = colonnes/2; // on repositionne le serpent au centre
        positionY = lignes/2;
        fill(153,5,5);
        text("Game Over !\nVous n'avez pas réussi à atteindre les 15 points!", width/2, height/2);
        player.pause(); // la musique s'arrête
        return;// on stop tout pour pouvoir afficher le score final

      }

    }
    // si le tête touche la pomme on gagne un point, une taille et on acélère 
    if (pomme.touche(positionX, positionY)) {
      score ++;  // un point de plus
      snakeTaille ++; // une taille en plus 
      tempo -=15; // on accelere la cadence
      // et on replace la pomme quelque part dans le jeu
      pomme.x = (int) random(colonnes);
      pomme.y = (int) random(lignes);
    }
      if (score == 15) {
        positionX = colonnes/2; // on repositionne le serpent au centre
        positionY = lignes/2;
        fill(153,5,5);
        text("Vous avez gagné!\nLes 15 points ont été atteints, félicitations !", width/2, height/2);
        player.pause(); // la musique s'arrête
        return;// on stop tout pour pouvoir afficher le score final
        }

    // on ajoute la tete à la l'ArrayList du serpent
    Point tete = new Point(positionX, positionY);
    snake.add(tete);
    // on contraint la taille du serpent à 'snakeTaille' elements 
    if (snake.size()>snakeTaille) snake.remove(0);

    dernierPas = millis();
  }
  noStroke();//pas de contours accentués pour le serpent 
  fill(255); // couleur du score.
   text(score, width-120, height-10);    // position du compteur du score
   text("score :",width-145, height-10); // position du mot "score :"
  fill(255); //couleur des essais
   text (essais, width/4, height-10);    // position du compteur des essais
   text ("essais :", width-405, height-10); // postion du mot "essais :"
  fill(104,75,64); // couleur du serpent.

  //on dessine chaque elements du serpent
  for (int i = snake.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
    Point point = (Point) snake.get(i);
    ellipse(point.x*pas + pas/2, point.y*pas + pas/2, pas, pas);
  }
 stroke(255,200,0);//les contours de la pomme sont dorés

  // et on dessine la pomme en rouge
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(pomme.x*pas + pas/2, pomme.y*pas + pas/2, pas, pas);



}

void keyPressed() {
  // on change la direction en fonction des fleche du clavier
  // mais on ne permet pas de revenir sur soi 
  switch(keyCode) {
    case RIGHT:
      if (direction!=3) direction=1;
      break;
    case LEFT:
      if (direction!=1) direction=3;
      break;
    case UP:
      if (direction!=2) direction=0;
      break;
    case DOWN:
      if (direction!=0) direction=2;
      break;
  }
 }

void mousePressed() {
  commencer = true;
}


class Point {
  int x; // position x
  int y; // et y


  Point(int _x, int _y) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
  }


  Boolean touche(int _x, int _y) {
    return ((_x==x)&&(_y==y));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to say you have a class function- you have a class named Point.

Think about it this way: you know how to use **primitive values** like int and boolean. For example, an int value can hold a single integer value. But what do you do when you want a single value to be represented by multiple primitive values? For example, you might want to keep track of a single **point**, which is both an X and a Y value.

The answer to that question is that you use a **class**. Put simply, a class is a collection of values (and methods) that represents a single **object**. For example, your `Point` class represents a single **point object**, which is made up of an X and a Y value.

If that sounds confusing, keep in mind that you're already using the `ArrayList` class, and all of your code is in a `PApplet` class behind the scenes. I also would guess that you got this code from the internet- I suggest trying to start from scratch instead of trying to work backwards from somebody else's code.

For more info on classes, check out [this](http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/objects/index) tutorial I wrote, or check out [the Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html).

Also, note that Processing has a PVector class, so you don't really need to create your own Point class.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations.
I will consult your website.